# What is the Intellisense Trigger in VS2005 emacs emulation mode?

Tags: emacs, visual-studio-2005, intellisense

I've enabled emacs keyboard mode in VS2005 and so far I'm in love.

The only issue I've run into is I can't find the hot key that triggers the IntelliSense menu. C-j no longer does the trick as it's mapped to something else.

So what is the emacs-mode IntelliSense trigger key?

Secondly, how would one go about finding out what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IntelliSense trigger is Alt-/ (M-/ in traditional emacs notation).

This and a lot of other formatting-related commands live in the submenus at the bottom of the Edit menu.